# QMake / Moc behave differently when MOD_DIR is set

Tags: c++, include, qmake, moc

I'm now working on a project that causes me headache.
I use some piece of code provided by a third party in which at one point, a MOC file is included at the end of a cpp file. Let's call those files respectively moc_problematic.cpp and problematic.cpp

If I leave MOC_DIR empty - by doing nothing or adding 'MOC_DIR = ' to my pro file, the generated project uses the MOC to generate moc_problematic.cpp (and all others), places in in my project's folder, and kind of automatically sees that it is included somewhere and shouldn't be compiled afterwards.

If I specify a custom MOD_DIR, the MOC generates all MOC files correctly and puts them into my MOC_DIR. Then the compiler compiles all moc files, including moc_problematic, and the build fails because some identifiers are unknown (as they are defined in problematic.cpp).

This behavior is identical whether I generate a makefile and use nmake or generate a vcproj and use Visual Studio.

Do anybody have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

PS I'm using Qt 5.3.1 with MSVC2013

Comment: I made progess: it seems that using a relative path gives better results:
MOC_DIR = $$relative_path($$MOC_DIR)

Comment: Hard to tell what's wrong here without seeing an example project. Are you saying that you set MOC_DIR to an absolute path, and then compilation breaks?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying :)
I can't give you my code (because NDA you know...) but, I found out that the same behavior occurs with the KDReports library: if you force MOC_DIR to an absolute path and try to build KDRepors as a DLL, you get exactly the same error.
Sometimes the error only triggers at the second build, for some reasons...